# `Window` `Width` and `Top` have local values

Tags: wpf, binding, snoop

My main window's `Height`, `Left`, `Top`, and `Width` are all bound to their respective viewmodel properties through a style. I can confirm that these four properties in the view model are only ever set to `1920`, `1920`, `118`, `1080` respectively.

But when I launch the app, the `Top` and `Width` properties on the main window are set to something else (`Width` will be `1440` and `Top` will be a random number usually less than `300`). What would cause this?

Here's what I see when I Snoop the app. Notice how `Top` and `Width` come from a `Local` Value Source:

[image: Before clear/reset]

Strangely, when I right-click on those properties in Snoop and tell it to "Clear/Reset", then those properties begin behaving. What is Snoop doing that fixes this?

[image: After clear/reset]

Other facts:

- The getters for the `Top` and `Width` viewmodel properties are only called once while the main window is being initialized. The stack trace runs through framework binding initialization code.
- The setters for the `Top` and `Width` viewmodel properties are only called once from the viewmodel constructor as it sets those properties to `118` and `1080` respectively.
- The bindings for these four properties are all two-way.
- None of these things cause the view's properties to change/be correct:

  - Changing the associated viewmodel properties at runtime, even after the view has been fully loaded.
  - Calling `UpdateLayout()` on the view.
  - Calling `InvalidateArrange()` on the view.
  - Calling `InvalidateMeasure()` on the view.
  - Calling `InvalidateProperty(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty)` on the view.
  - Calling `InvalidateVisual()` on the view.
- I have searched and searched and do not see any code anywhere touching the view's `Top` or `Width` properties (other than the style bindings).

Here's the style:

[image: Bindings in the style]

Sorry I had to blank out type names and some other things—it's a company application. If it helps, the main window/the view is at the end of a long inheritance line with `Window` as its great-great grandaddy. I'm trying to make the main window more reusable by MVVM-ing it—formerly these layout properties were set in code-behind in the view, and the view had constructor parameters :'( That's related to why I need to key the style, and why the style is based on other stuff. But none of the inherited types manipulate layout properties.

P.S. I've seen other people complain about how hard it is to resize WPF's `Window`. The most commonly suggested solution is to bind `MinWidth` and `MaxWidth` as well as `Width`. When I do that then the `Width` is indeed forced to the value I want, but you can't resize the window, the `Width` property still has its `Local` Value Source, and `Top` is still incorrect.

Comment: Snoop's "Clear/Reset" is doing `DependencyObject.ClearValue(DependencyProperty)`, or `mainView.ClearValue(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty)`

Comment: Maybe I should read [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.top?view=netframework-4.7.2): "[Top] cannot be set through a style"

Comment: Set the properties of the window directly with local values, e.g. `Top="{Binding Top, Mode=TwoWay}" `. Local values take precedence over values set by styles.

Comment: @mm8 Unfortunately in my case that would lead to duplicated code. I would need to put those bindings in each of the views which inherits from this one. Having these bindings in a keyed style is my workaround for the duplication. Thanks, though!

Comment: You might want to consider creating a custom window class that binds to these properties then.

Answer (score 0):

Given that ["[Top] cannot be set through a style"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.top?view=netframework-4.7.2), and given [the complications with binding Window.Width](https://www.google.com/search?q=wpf+window+bind+width), I solved this a different way.

I created this attached property called `WindowLayout` and bound it to a viewmodel property in my style:

```
public static class WindowLayoutBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LayoutProperty = DependencyPropertyHelpers.RegisterAttached(
        (Window x) => GetLayout(x),
        new PropertyMetadata(HandleLayoutChanged));

    private static void HandleLayoutChanged(
        DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(d is Window window))
            return;
        if (!(e.NewValue is Rect rect))
            return;
        window.Height = rect.Height;
        window.Left = rect.Left;
        window.Top = rect.Top;
        window.Width = rect.Width;
    }

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(Window))]
    public static Rect GetLayout(Window window) =>
        window.GetValue(LayoutProperty) is Rect rect
            ? rect
            : default;

    public static void SetLayout(Window window, Rect rect) =>
        window.SetValue(LayoutProperty, rect);
}
```

`DependencyPropertyHelpers.RegisterAttached` is a shorthand helper method for creating the attached property in the way you might expect.

Usage in the style:

```
<Setter
    Property="WindowLayoutBehavior.Layout"
    Value="{Binding WindowLayout, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Now when I Snoop the app, `Height`, `Left`, `Top`, and `Width` all show as having `Local` Value Sources, and they change when the viewmodel property changes, so that works for me.